# In a xml file,How can I get the data in a label depending on another label in the same level of node?

Tags: java, xml

I have a xml file like the following:

```
<root>
<doc>
  <str name="name">test1</str>
  <str name="uri">test1.com</str>
</doc>
<doc>
  <str name="name">test2</str>
  <str name="uri">test1.com</str>
</doc>
 </root>
```

I want to parsing the file. I could get the name using the dom4j.

```
for(Element doc : docs ){
          List<Element> strs = doc.elements();
          for(Element str : strs ){
              if("name".equals(str.attributeValue("name"))){
                 System.out.println(str.getText());  
                    }
                }
            }
```

How can I get the data of 'uri' after I getting the data of 'name'under the same node 'doc'?

Thaks a lot!

Comment: first get all the doc nodes. Then iterate through that nodes and get children nodes of each doc node

Answer (score 0):

Isn't enough the following:

```
for(Element doc : docs ){
   List<Element> strs = doc.elements();
   for(Element str : strs ){
      if("name".equals(str.attributeValue("name"))){
         System.out.println(str.getText());  
      }
      if("uri".equals(str.attributeValue("name"))){
         System.out.println(str.getText());  
      }
   }
}
```

as you're looping through the child of "doc"

Answer (score 0):

```
        for(Element doc : docs ){
                  List<Element> strs = doc.elements();
                  for(Element str : strs ){
                     String name="";
                     String  uri=""
                     if("name".equals(str.attributeValue("name"))){
                         name=str.getText();  
                     }
                     if("uri".equals(str.attributeValue("name"))){
                         uri=str.getText();  
                     }
                  }
                  System.out.println("name:"+name+" uri:"+uri); 
        }
```